# Why Value error passed when casting content-length to int in cgi.py Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, http-headers

Why Value error passed when casting `content-length` to int in [cgi.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/cgi.py) Python in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Lib/cgi.py#L460) line? When `ValueErrror` raised, clen will be remain `-1`.

```
clen = -1
    if 'content-length' in self.headers:
        try:
            clen = int(self.headers['content-length'])
         except ValueError:
             pass
```

Comment: What's the result of `print(repr(self.headers['content-length']))`

Comment: @DawidFieluba `-1`

Comment: I think I did not get the question right at the first time ;) correct me if I'm wrong, what you're asking is: Why are they ignoring this *ValueError* exception and leaving `self.length = -1`?

Comment: @DawidFieluba Yes, sry for my bad English.